# how to find median of 5 sorted list in O(logn) time?

Tags: algorithm, median

Here is the question:

There are 5 sorted list A,B,C,D,E, which has the same length n. The question is to find an algorithm that can median of this 5 list in O(logn) time. I am thinking of a general idea but I could not figure out the exact complexity it takes.

Assume the median of A,B,C,D,E is a,b,c,d,e. And we have `a<b<c<d<e`. It is obvious that I could throw away the first half of array A and the last half of array E. Now I have 5 new arrays: B,C,D stay the same, each has n numbers; A' and E' each has n/2 numbers left. I then compute the median of A' and E' as a' and e', compare them to b,c,d. If the new order of 5 medians is `a'<b<e'<c<d`, then I through away the first half of a' (n/4 numbers) and the last n/4 numbers of array D, because we need to throw away equal numbers on both sides of the final median. The process continue...

I have a kind of feeling that the algorithm is O(logn). But I don't know the exact proof. In the first logn steps, we can surely reduce the candidate numbers to 3n, adding up all the remaining numbers of the 5 lists. The first time we kick out n numbers, the second time at least n/2 numbers, the third time n/4 numbers and so on. However, I don't know how to analysis after I get 3n remaining numbers.

Can this algorithm actually give me O(logn)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it actually can. Just look at those statements

- We can get final result only if we have one list. Unless we have at least two lists, we can't speak about this.
- Every step of algorithm we're cutting by half two of lists. If there is only one element in list, we're deleting whole list.
- Let's count, how many steps take it to delete the list. On first deletion we'll delete n/2 items, an second - n/4 and so on till one element left, when we're finally deleting the list. It will take about log(n) operations (don't know if it's really log(n) or log(n)+1 but in both cases it is O(log(n)) ).
- So, we need to eliminate 5 lists (operation of finding median in last list can be generalized to operation of reducing lists). It takes O(log(n)) to eliminate one of them, so we'll do all the stuff also in O(log(n)), cause 5 is constant.

Comment: thank you for your comment. However, I still have questions: how to assure that after logn steps, I can eliminate a whole list of length n? It may be the case that the 5 lists each has some numbers left...

Comment: Yes, it isn't guaranteed that after log(n) steps you'll get exactly one list eliminated (and four other left). But it is clear that after log(n) operations of deleting half list will become empty. Each step of your algorithm does 2 operations of deleting half. In worst case we need eliminate all list step by step until there is only one list with one element. It'll take 5*log(n) operations from us.

Comment: yes. You are right. I am fully understand the question now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @OleGG Sorry, The answer makes no sense to me, can you try and explain in a bit more detail? Possibly with an example.